# Unable to get wifi adapter working on my Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

After following the guide on raspberrypi.org (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) I thought it was working as I got an IP address, but after disconnecting the networking cable the pi was unreachable until plugged in again. Am I missing something?

This is my output from "ifconfig".

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:38:b1:11  
      inet addr:192.168.1.22  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::9064:76fa:22d9:79a1/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:972 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1459 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:206581 (201.7 KiB)  TX bytes:169011 (165.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ef:c6:1b:c9  
      inet addr:192.168.0.22  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::7b9b:5b00:508d:3492/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2219 errors:0 dropped:9 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:356 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:501540 (489.7 KiB)  TX bytes:41788 (40.8 KiB)
```

Comment: The wifi dongle kept going to sleep, that's why it didn't work. Solution how to fix that is found here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34794/how-to-disable-wi-fi-dongle-sleep-mode